# Error while opening Android app

Tags: java, android

i am new to android development and i am writing an app for my college project .The app transmits a string of data stored in shared preferences .The data is stored by one time setup screen which is never shown again.The issue is after first time,when app is started again it shows that "app has unfortunately stopped working "and when i click ok the app starts.Can anybody tell me why this is happening?
Code:

```
package com.example.homeautomation.zigbeehomeauto;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
    NdefMessage msg;
    NfcAdapter nfcadapter;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public String pass2 ;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        SharedPreferences check = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
         String Pass = check.getString("Str", "Nothing");
        pass2 = Pass;
        nfcadapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (nfcadapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();

        }







    }




    public void ExApp(View v) {

        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public void Nsend(View v)
    {
        byte[] stringBytes = pass2.getBytes();

        nfcadapter.setNdefPushMessage(msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", stringBytes)

        }),this);



    }
}
```

Logcat Ouput:

```
04-07 12:04:38.478  10836-10836/com.example.homeautomation.zigbeehomeauto E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.homeautomation.zigbeehomeauto, PID: 10836
    android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.homeautomation.zigbeehomeauto/com.example.homeautomation.zigbeehomeauto.SetupScreen} did not call through to super.onCreate()
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5752)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check in your **SetupScreen.java** do you have `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
after `onCreate()` Method is starts .

post your SetupScreen.java code also ..

Answer (score 1):

Your `onCreate()` method of class `SetupScreen` do not call the `super.onCreate()`. Add the statement and the error should go away.